# Questions about data loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation, rx-java, viewmodel

I have a problem with data loading that I can't solve. When I use navigation to go to a new fragment and then go back, the data loading of recyclerview becomes very strange, its data will be duplicated, but the data I print out with log is not duplicated, I am very puzzled, but I can't solve it, this makes me very unhappy. I hope someone can give me some suggestions, I am a pure Java project. My main code is at [this link](https://github.com/luren-dc/MusicDownloader/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/luren/md/ui/home). The fragment refers to HomeFragment

Comment: This is demo apk [download](https://github.com/luren-dc/MusicDownloader/blob/master/apk/MusicDownloader_1.0_20231001192046.apk)

Comment: This problem has been solved.